# Cannot participate in meta sites unless previously having participated in regular sites on iOS

Tags: bug, ios-app, per-site-meta

On the mobile app for iOS, you are unable to participate in the meta sites unless you have previously participated in the regular sites.  It gives the following error:

```
Error
Could not perform this request with
your account.  Please try logging back
in.  If this persists, let us know on
meta.
```

This happens when attempting to vote an existing question.  I am logged in.  (I have not attempting asking a question for fear of the repercussions of then deleting it.  I have not tested it on the Android app either.)

This is not an issue on the website.

This is not so much a question as a bug report, so I am not sure what kind of answer I am expecting here.

Comment: A bug report will often be answered by an SE dev, with an explanation of a fix. It may just be tagged [tag:status-completed] at some point tho.

Comment: I had this same problem yesterday with the newest iOS app version 1.3.0.208 on a different site. Since this question is being considered a duplicate, I'll upvote that one and hope it gets resolved.